# How to check if an Array is present in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to find out whether an Array is present in an JavaScript object.

Dummy example:

Given a Javascript Object containing an Array. and we dont know if there is an Array present in the Object.

```
var dummyObject = { 
backgroundcolor: '#000',
 color: '#fff',
 arr: ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
};
```

Now I want to check if there is an array in this object and if  there is print all the elements of that Array.

Currently I am onto one solution i.e. to Iterate each key and check each if them if there is an array in it using Array.isArray(key).

Any help would be great.

Comment: "*Currently I am onto one solution i.e. to Iterate each key and check each if them if there is an array in it using Array.isArray(key).*" That sounds good. What is the problem with it?

Comment: I want to know if there is any method available in Javascript which can be used to check if array is there rather than iterating for each key

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I had been asked this question in an interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.isArray` is the correct method for going about this. Iterating through each key is pretty simple too. Then once you find the item, just log it to the console:

```js
var dummyObject = {
  backgroundcolor: '#000',
  color: '#fff',
  arr: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
};

const arr = Object.entries(dummyObject).find(([, v]) => Array.isArray(v));
if (arr) console.log(arr[1]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You can use `some` with `Object.values` if you just want a Boolean determining whether an array exists inside an object:

```js
var dummyObject = {
  backgroundcolor: '#000',
  color: '#fff',
  arr: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
};

const arrInObj = Object.values(dummyObject).some(e => Array.isArray(e));
console.log(arrInObj);
```

And if you want, you can avoid using `Array.isArray` and check for the existence of the `map` property instead ([à la code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80105/83351)):

```js
var dummyObject = {
  backgroundcolor: '#000',
  color: '#fff',
  arr: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
};

const arrInObj = Object.values(dummyObject).some(({ map }) => map);
console.log(arrInObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dummyObject.arr){
console.log('arr is present')
}else{
console.log('arr is not present')
}
```

Comment: Seems that OP wanted to check whether `dummyObject.arr` is an **Array**